# How to display a file thumbnail in browser when fetching blobs from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: reactjs, azure, http, azure-blob-storage, fastapi

simply saying I want to achieve something like this:[image]

I am building the website using React and FastAPI. Currently I am able to upload files to Azure Blob Storage, and download them by generating a SAS token. The logic is:

User clicks the name of displayed blob -> use the name to find corresponding file in Bob Storage ->return an url that contains the SAS token -> browser visit the url and download the file straight away.

Therefore, now the only way of accessing the file is by visiting the returned url. However, I wanted to get all file's thumbnail when loading the page, and I'm not sure how to achieve that. Some ways I researched:

- npm doc-viewer/pdf-viewer that works by passing in the url of the file. Problem: the returned url is something like:
  `https://notewebapp.blob.core.windows.net/notes/277899118_1435932406849269_4377085740139427410_n.jpg?se=2022-07-12T00%3A06%3A08Z&sp=r&sv=2021-06-08&sr=b&sig=jxhr4c55u2rfRauCs1e7UqYeOJF2voflZWJh0b3zm%2BM%3D`. Which will straight up invoke download window when accessed instead of opening up the actual file. The reason could be it is a stream object. For example by inspecting, a supposed pdf file's returned content type is `application/octet-stream`. So how do I better control the type of object the Azure SDK returns? Even if I can manage to get `application/pdf`, it still doesn't work in these modules.
- Browser downloading the file before generating the thumbnail. Problem: how do I achieve that using React and FastAPI? And wouldn't it add too much pressure on the browser side?

If anyone wanted to have a look at the current display name/upload/download logic, [Click here to see the python code](https://github.com/charl1ecloud/notebank-webapp/blob/main/backend/app/upload.py).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d recommend to create thumbnail versions upon creation of the images and fetch all the Sas urls via FastAPI, and render the response from your frontend. Fetching all full files is not really scalable and results in more network traffic than required.

Comment: yeah, I thought of that too, I wonder if this is the standard way of how the industry does it.

Comment: For scalable applications, yes this is a very normal practice.